# C++ Cross-compiler from windows to mac os

Tags: c++, windows, macos, cross-compiling

I have a c++ library that is currently being built separately for the different OS. Windows and Linux are built from a Windows computer with WSL and Mac OS is built separately. For automatization purposes, I would like to be able to build the library for Mac OS also from the same Windows installation.

However, I'm having difficulties to find a tool to cross-compile from windows to mac os. I would appreciate any hint to achieve this.

The targeted goal is to be able to simply build for all platforms in one click using scripts, without requiring to have a computer always running and waiting for a build signal.

Comment: Are you using a CI tool for building where you can add an osx agent (i.e. Jenkins etc)?

Comment: I am building manually a CMake project configured with CLion, there is no CI in the process currently

Comment: Welcome to Apple's walled garden, it's difficult to compile code for a Mac on anything other than a Mac. You might have some luck with http://darwine.sourceforge.net/download.php

Comment: @Infenix as Alan states above cross compiling is a pain. If you are going to do frequent builds I would suggest you getting into setting up a local Jenkins instance (could just be a container) and the adding build separate build agents for the different target platforms you want. It costs some time on the initial investment, but this way is really the most appropriate way to reach your target goal.